# Unlock method for iOS 5.1 [MobileSubstrate]

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak

I'm trying to find out where the method for unlock the device is. I'm using SBAwayLockBar but SpringBoard crashes and returns that an instance of SBAwayLockBar may not respond to the selector, unlock. So, is there a private method that would allow me to unlock the device on iOS 5.1?

Comment: Have you tried activator

Answer (score 1):

I think the  the function(s) for unlocking the device are in the SBAwayController.h.(I honestly just took a quick look a the header file). I found these quite interesting.

```
- (void)attemptUnlockFromSource:(int)source;    // 0x441d5
- (void)attemptUnlock;
- (void)_finishedUnlockAttemptWithStatus:(BOOL)status;
```